# Работа с https протоколом в Delphi XE7 (Indy 10)

Tags: delphi, https, delphi-xe7, indy

На Delphi XE7 пишу код:

```
url := 'https://'+_Setting+'/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id='+_ID;
ListMessages.Text := '';
IDHttp1.HandleRedirects := true;
IDHttp1.AllowCookies := true;
ContentStr := IdHTTP1.Get(URL);
ListMessages.Lines.Add('-----------------------');
ListMessages.Lines.Add('Текст полученный от сервера: ');
ListMessages.Lines.Add(ContentStr);
```

Выдает следующую ошибку:

> iohandler value is not valid

Как её победить? В сети пишут, что надо подключать библиотеки SSL, но мне хочется обойти малой кровью при решении этой задачи.

Comment: HTTPS предполагает шифрованное соединение, и сейчас в роли таких в ходу SSL и TLS. Так что либо организуете одно из них, либо не используете HTTPS. Третьего (пока) не дано.

Comment: Можно перейти на более новые версии, там есть компоненты (System.Net), которые используют нативные возможности целевой ОС (любой) и не требуют наличия OpenSSL. Можно задействовать сторонние компоненты (в принципе, Indy и есть таковые) - например Synopse.

Comment: забудьте про срашный Indy. в XE7 уже появился замечательный компонент `THTTPClient`. объявлен в `System.Net.HttpClient`. мультиплатформенный, проверен и работает под Android, Windows & MAC OS. не требует дополнительных OpenSSL DLL

Comment: Ну если используешь SSL, то и пропиши его в `IDHttp1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;`